# How to create a button in TinyMCE 4 that increments font size

Tags: tinymce-4

Has anyone managed to create a button in TinyMCE 4 that will increment the font size of the selected text by, say, 1px?

The problem I'm having is getting ahold of the  selected text, whether it's in a span already or not.
I'm willing to modify the TinyMCE source.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: This one works for me: `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&lt;span style=&#34font-size: 2em&#34&gt;' + tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent() + '&lt;/span&gt;'); return false">big</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to modify the source code, you can create a plugin.

Here is the documentation of how to create a plugin for TinyMCE:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin

based on that you can create your own button ([see working example](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Z9eaab/5))
here is part of the code:

```js
var currentFontSize = new Number($(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode()).css('font-size').replace('px','')); //remove the px part
currentFontSize =  currentFontSize + 1; //increase font by one
            
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('mycustomformat', {
  inline : 'span',
  styles : {'font-size' : currentFontSize + 'px'} //this is the font size incremented by one
});

tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('mycustomformat'); //apply the format to the selected text
```

Comment: I'm not sure _why_ this solution works. The first line gets the font size of the _node_  containing the selection, which might be a 'p'. But the selection itself  might have a different font size, and certainly will after the first time you run the function by clicking the button.  Yet the font-size read the next time is the bumped font size.  Strangely, this solution doesn't work if you try to do it with letter-spacing, i.e., make a button that increments letter-spacing of a selection by 1px.  I hope you're still following the question and have time to clear this up.  Thanks.